# PHP mysql real escape using update

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using Real Escape String to stop characters like ` bringing up SQL errors.
This is part of my code, it should update from a form. I need help figuring out how to do the escape string using update.

```
$Comments = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Comments']);
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
$sql="UPDATE Worklog SET Comments = '$Comments' WHERE id = '$id'";
mysql_query($sql);

    <form action="comments.php?id=<?php echo $stuff['id'];?>" method="post">

    <br />
    Comments: <br />
    <textarea name="Comments"  method="post" cols="20" rows="5" wrap="hard"><?php echo $stuff['Comments']; ?></textarea> <br />

    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="makeitgos" />
    <br />
    <br />
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

`

Comment: care to add the error you're seeing?

Comment: Note the mysql_ functions are deprecated. You should probably start using PDO as that will handle the escaping for you.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I'm looking into PDO but still cannot get it to work, would you be able to provide an example using my code above? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Liquorvicar in that PDO seems to make things much easier.

I'm only just learning PHP, but I believe that you can escape the ' character in a double quoted string by using a delimiter. Also, when I tried this on my own MySQL database, the query didn't work unless I used double quotes around the variables. See working code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE Worklog SET Comments = \"$Comments\" WHERE id = \"$id\"";
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code just seems fine, using `mysql_real_escape_string` is useful if you are still using the mysql library. Note however that I'd suggest checking whether `$id` is numeric (with `is_numeric($id)`) before applying it to your SQL statement.

Furthermore, you could look into [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and PDO. Using prepared statements has the advantage that MySQL injection is less likely (note that SQL injection a security vulnerability, not just an inconvenience) and that your SQL queries will typically be a bit faster (especially when reusing your queries).

Speaking of escaping, you should really escape your `<?php echo $_POST[x]; ?>`'s, since these may still cause some issues if, for example, `"><script>alert('hai');</script>` is entered as id or comment. You should escape these using [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars).

**Edit:** Answer did not entirely fit the question.

Comment: How does that make a difference?

Comment: Sorry, it didn't. I fixed my post.